# Mockito Error -"there were zero interactions with this mock"

Tags: android, mockito

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    // Send SiteCatalyst data

    //create trigger to adobe analytics when the view visible
    mMeasurement = MeasurementWrapper.create(MeasurementEnum.SPLASH);
    mMeasurement.trackSplashState();
```

> here I called trackSplashState inside onCreate method in Splash screen.

```
   @Override
    public void trackSplashState() {
        HashMap<String, Object> data = createCommonData();
        MeasureServiceImpl.StartStatus status = mMeasureService.getLaunchStatus();
        switch (status) {
            case INSTALL: {
                data.put("appevent.install", "install");
                break;
            }
            case LAUNCH: {
                data.put("appevent.launch", "launch");
                break;
            }
            case UPDATE: {
                data.put("appevent.update", "update");
                break;
            }
        }
        mAnalyticsService.trackState(mType, data);
    }
```

> Method functionality inside MeassurementWrapper.java class

```
@Override
public void trackState(MeasurementEnum mType, HashMap<String, Object> data, String... additionalData) {
    try {
        String stateName = MeasurementWrapper.DEVICE_NAME + ":" + String.format(mType.getName(), additionalData);
        // Check last Adobe Analytic page value is same to the current page value if so avoiding it send to the Adobe analytics tracking
        if (!isPageAndUrlMatching(mType,data)) {
            Analytics.trackState(stateName, data);
        }
    } catch (MissingFormatArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

> Implementation of the trackState method inside service(AnalyticsServiceImpl).
>
> ```
>     <-------- Test Class -------------->
> ```

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = TestConfig.SDK)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AdobeAnalyticsTriggerTest {

    private ArgumentCaptor<MeasurementEnum> enumArgumentCaptor;

    @Module(includes = TestAppModule.class, injects = AdobeAnalyticsTriggerTest.class, overrides = true)
    static class TestModule {}

    @Inject
    Context context;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<HashMap<String, Object>> data;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<String[]> varargs;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Services.initialize(new AdobeAnalyticsTriggerTest.TestModule()).inject(this);
        enumArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MeasurementEnum.class);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTrackSplashscreen_afterOnCreate(){
        SplashActivity splashActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(SplashActivity.class).create().get();
        Measurement measurement = mock(splashActivity.mMeasurement);
        verify(((MeasurementWrapper) measurement).mAnalyticsService, times(1)).trackState(enumArgumentCaptor.capture(), data.capture());

    }

    /**
     * Mocks measurement (so stuff is not sent to sitecatalyst)
     * @return measurement
     */
    private Measurement mock(Measurement measurement) {
        MeasurementWrapper wrapper = (MeasurementWrapper) measurement;

        wrapper.mAnalyticsService = Mockito.spy(new AnalyticsServiceImpl());

        // overwrite sendTrackAction() to prevent logs being sent somewhere
        doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> null).when(wrapper.mAnalyticsService).trackAction(any(MeasurementEnum.class), (HashMap) anyMapOf(String.class, Objects.class));

        // overwrite sendStateAction() to prevent logs being sent somewhere
        doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> null).when(wrapper.mAnalyticsService).trackState(any(MeasurementEnum.class), (HashMap) anyMapOf(String.class, Objects.class));

        return wrapper;
    }
```

> I need to test(**shouldTrackSplashscreen_afterOnCreate**) trackState method of the AnalyticsServiceImpl calling when splash screen call onCreate method. But the issue is that I always get an error from Mockito that **Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock**.Can someone help me to fix this issue. It will be a big help for me. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add you're test code between the mocking and the verification part, example see below.

Currently there is no method call done on the mock, hence you get the error message from mockito.

```
    @Test
    public void shouldTrackSplashscreen_afterOnCreate(){
        SplashActivity splashActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(SplashActivity.class).create().get();
        Measurement measurement = mock(splashActivity.mMeasurement);

        // ... add test code here ...

        verify(((MeasurementWrapper) measurement).mAnalyticsService, times(1)).trackState(enumArgumentCaptor.capture(), data.capture());

    }
```